# How can i add custom module in homepage using opencart 2.1?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I want display menu in different design. Homepage menu is totally different from other pages. So i want to create menu in module. I'm trying to create and also followed the online tutorials but modules are showing in list where i can add to homepage. See image i want to show module in this list. Also i don't know how can i create module in proper way. Thanks[image]

Comment: Show what you have done!

Comment: By the way, you should not create a module for your homepage. As homepage will also include header which contains menu. Perhaps you should add a condition in your header file to display the different menu on different page.

Comment: @VedPandya You're saying right but problem is that i have to show menu between two modules which are showing in homepage through conten-top that's why i'm asking about modules

Comment: Refer this http://www.php-dev-zone.com/2015/02/opencart-custom-module-development.html for custom module development.